# Visualizing DNS named query logs

Tags: log-files, bind, visualization, named-conf

Anyone out has suggestions as to what is available for visualizing logs produced by named?

Comment: What information or trends are you trying to see, and what quantity of log data?  Is it just for point in time analysis or ongoing visualisation?  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) will do some basic visualisation from a performance and availability perspective.  It's free to use for smallish quantities of logs and it's easy to install.